# Include Insurance Turn On/Off

Tags: forms, gui-design, checkboxes

I have a form that asks travel agents if they want to include insurance for multiple guests. A checkbox is best for on/off, but I'm not 100% confident with my labeling. A few options are:

#### Guest Insurance

Bobby Smith
[ ] $87.00 Include Insurance | Straight forward, but "include" gets in the way.

Nathan Smith
[ ] $87.00 Insurance? | Stating a question.

Bobby Smith
[ ] $87.00 Yes, include Insurance. | A simple statement.

Bobby Smith
[ ] $87.00 | Just the price; the form header states "Insurance".

Keep in mind that multiple guests are listed. What option would you use? Why?

Comment: Is it going to be obvious or ambiguous that the price is for each guest? If you include a checkbox next to each person, then you'll also need a 'select all' control as well. Another thing to consider is the default option for the control, so if it is ticked by default then you'll need to rephrase things differently.

Comment: Insurance is not "ticked" by default. I'm showing the "tick" to communicate a checkbox.

Comment: I'm really just asking about the labeling, but the "select all" should be a given.

Answer (score 2):

A checkbox represents a (yes/no) answer, so put the question after it first.

[yes,] include insurance at $87.00 per year.

Comment: Why would you need to use a question format when the price and the word "insurance" communicates the same thing? Seems like the question format would make it hard to scan for the most essential information (price, insurance) in a list of guests.

Comment: http://www.andera.com/media/122612/eye_tracker_399x464.jpg
Notice how few hits the heading gets in a form? Not exactly the ultimate proof, but people are inherently lazy, especially with (big) forms, so you'd want to hand them everything on a silver platter.